# AWS Linux Server install R package

Tags: amazon-web-services, rstudio-server, install.packages

[image]I try to install the package "data.table" (and "aws.s3)" via Rstudio Server on an Amazon Linux instance following this guide: 
http://stanke.co/category/r/

Unfortunately, I get the following error message. I really don't know what else to do.

Can anybody help? I installed devtools and I am able to install other packages such as xml2, devtools and deplyr.

Comment: I posted a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576682/r-and-data-table-on-aws

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on AWS and already fixed.
You need first install gcc64 and openmp shared support library.

```
sudo yum install gcc64
sudo yum install libgomp
```

Then under your user home create an .R folder with a Makevars file in it, with the following content (it will tell to R which compiler to use):

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc64
CXX = /usr/bin/g++
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
```

I hope it's working for you as well ...

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't worked for me - where should I create the .R folder? I have created it where I think it should be (`cd ~; mkdir .R`) and also in the Sagemaker directory where the notebooks themselves are stored...

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `dmlc-core`.

This link will provide more information:

[A common bricks library for building scalable and portable distributed machine learning](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core)

Comment: I did the following already:


    sudo yum -y install libcurl-devel openssl-devel 
    sudo yum -y install libxml2 libxml2-devel

However, the problem is still there. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know enough about the R environment. The problem with your code is that the include file "omp.h" is missing. That file is part of the dmlc-core library.

Comment: Ok thanks so far! What information could I provide, that might help?

Answer (score 1):

based on https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/200, I think this issue is due to a g++ compatability issue. It might also explain why when I installed devtools it kept giving me [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
so run:
`sudo yum remove gcc72-c++.x86_64 libgcc72.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install R-devel
```

Then you should be able to run the installation command.