# R and data.table on AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, data.table

This is a very strange error I am running into trying to install a specific R library on AWS EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI). A link in the [AWS forums here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=828265&#828265), posted by someone else, actually highlights my issue well.

The main / relevant part of the error message is:

```
data.table.h:6:12: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
#include <omp.h>
```

I did some research (while I'm not sure), I think this is related to whether or not there is an OpenMP enabled compiler on the server. The *data.table* installation page on GitHub itself discusses this a bit [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), but I'm not sure how to update or fix this on my EC2 instance.

Any help with this is appreciated.

EDIT - this is a new problem, as i was able to successfully install *data.table* on a previous, similar EC2 instance less than a month ago.

EDIT 2 - I got around this issue by taking a previous EC2 instance of mine with data.table already installed on it, and creating a custom AMI from it. By using this custom AMI when launching new instances, they already came with the data.table library installed. If I notice AWS resolve this issue on its own, I'll try to remember to come back and update this post!

Comment: What do you have in `~/.R/Makevars`

Comment: I deleted the instance that I was struggling with, so I'm not sure what that file had in it.

Comment: I found the following instructions and these worked for us:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307251/aws-linux-server-install-r-package

Comment: this had a similar answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307251/aws-linux-server-install-r-package

Comment: This answer may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307251/aws-linux-server-install-r-package

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that data.table doesn't play nice with the default gcc compiler (gcc72-c++.x86_64 gets installed as a dependency of R-devel.x86_64). Point R to an older version by adding

```
CC=gcc64
```

in `~/.R/Makevars`. If you start from a "clean" Amazon Linux AMI this file doesn't exist and you can just type

```
mkdir ~/.R
echo "CC=gcc64" >> ~/.R/Makevars
```

Answer (score 10):

For some reason setting `CC=gcc64` in the `~/.R/Makevars` did not work for me. R was still using default `gcc` to compile.

However there is another option. You can edit the `Makeconf` file that R uses during compilation directly. If you're using Amazon Linux the file location is `/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf`. Once you locate the file the trick is just the same, that is to change the `CC = gcc` to `CC = gcc64`. You also might want to make sure that `gcc64` is installed by running `sudo yum install gcc64`.

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/CC = gcc -m64/CC = gcc64 -m64/g' /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf`

Answer (score 2):

I have the following workaround.

1) Connect with `ssh`.

2) Download package source

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/data.table_1.10.4-3.tar.gz
```

3) Install package

```
R CMD INSTALL data.table_1.10.4-3.tar.gz
```

This will install the package in the local package directory, not necessarily the one of the RStudio user(s).

4) Use `.libPaths()` in R and RStudio to figure out where packages are stored.

5) Copy package into the desired directory using `sudo cp -R SOURCE DEST`.

**Remark:**  This is a workaround not a solution because you need to install each package manually this way, i.e. handling dependencies can be cumbersome, but at least `data.table` works now.