# Fatal error: auc_.cpp:2:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, r, amazon-web-services, compiler-errors

I'm running RServer Studio on a Linux box on AWS.

I tried to install `ModelMetrics`, a dependency for `caret`, and received this error:

```
auc_.cpp:2:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [auc_.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ModelMetrics’
```

This is the full output message

```
Installing package into ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ModelMetrics_1.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 16974 bytes (16 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 16 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ModelMetrics’ ...
** package ‘ModelMetrics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I"/opt/R/3.5.3/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I"/opt/R/3.5.3/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c auc_.cpp -o auc_.o
auc_.cpp:2:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [auc_.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ModelMetrics’
* removing ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/ModelMetrics’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ModelMetrics’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpr06k8i/downloaded_packages’
```

I looked around SO and it looks like there is an error with the compiler. I tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576682/r-and-data-table-on-aws), specifically I ran these commands

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
mkdir ~/.R
echo "CC=gcc64" >> ~/.R/Makevars
sudo sed -i 's/CC = gcc -m64/CC = gcc64 -m64/g' /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf
```

Even after restarting RStudio Server, I get the same output and error message.

It looks like this error is very similar to the [problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990296/how-to-include-omp-h-in-os-x/52871786#52871786). I still don't have a solution after following those instructions, but I did find the location of my omp.h file.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.4.6/include/omp.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/include/omp.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/include/omp.h
```

I installed `Developer Tools` and updated the `Makeconf` file using these commands.

```
sudo sed -i 's/CC = gcc -m64/CC = gcc64 -m64/g' /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Then, I added these lines to the `Makevars` config file.

```
mkdir ~/.R
vi ~/.R/Makevars

CC=gcc
VER=64
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CXX11=g++$(VER)
CXX14=g++$(VER)
```

I restarted the RStudio Server and tried to install `ModelMetrics` and received this error, the same as before.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ModelMetrics_1.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 16974 bytes (16 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 16 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ModelMetrics’ ...
** package ‘ModelMetrics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I"/opt/R/3.5.3/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I"/opt/R/3.5.3/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c auc_.cpp -o auc_.o
auc_.cpp:2:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [auc_.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ModelMetrics’
* removing ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/ModelMetrics’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ModelMetrics’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpTSUlz4/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: what is your gcc --version?

Comment: I started a brand new linux machine and got `gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)`

Comment: Note that none of the `omp.h` files you found are for gcc version 7.2.1.

Comment: The new error log shows that `g++` is still used instead of `g++64`. What is the output of `R CMD config CXX`?

Comment: The output is g++64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was something wrong with the version of `gcc` on the linux box.

Per the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307251/aws-linux-server-install-r-package), I was able to fix the problem with these two lines of code.

```
sudo yum remove gcc72-c++.x86_64 libgcc72.x86_64
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have configured R to use `gcc64`  when compiling C files, but C++ files will still be compiled with `g++` instead of `g++64`. The following configuration in `~/.R/Makevars` will change that consistently:

```
VER=64
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CXX11=g++$(VER)
CXX14=g++$(VER)
```

Since the above does not work for you, you might be affected by the same issues as this user: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49876044/8416610 In that case you can edit R's `Makeconf` file with

```
sudo sed -i 's/g++/g++64/' $(R RHOME)/etc/Makeconf
```

(assuming you alredy changed `gcc`  to `gcc64`)

Comment: I'm not sure how to make a config file. Do I just copy and paste those commands?

Comment: I added that, and I also installed Development Tools and ran `sudo sed -i 's/CC = gcc -m64/CC = gcc64 -m64/g' /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf`, but I get the same error

Comment: @Cauder Please post the full error output after this change.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks Ralf.

Comment: Is it possible that I should delete gcc 7.1 since my older version has an omp file?

Comment: @Cauder Some peopel had successs with that: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272761. But nore the caveat in the last message.

Comment: Got it! These two lines fixed it `sudo yum remove gcc72-c++.x86_64 libgcc72.x86_64
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

Comment: I see your link had the same information. If you add it to your post, I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks for your help, I'm glad we got through this!

Comment: @Cauder it makes more sense if you accept your own answer. I am not using Amazon Linux, so it I cannot give advise on which packages to install/remove. BTW, the final comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111148/8416610 is also interesting. For some reason gcc 7.2 in Amazon Linux is compiled without OpenMP support.