# Caret package failing to install with non-zero exit status in Azure Notebooks

Tags: r, azure, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install the caret package in Azure Jupyter notebook, but I am getting the below warnings and exiting with non-zero exit status.

I tried installing the packages in several ways as listed in other answers and in forums such as:

```
#1
install.packages('caret', dependencies=TRUE)
```

Errors:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/nbuser/R’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘recipes’

Warning message in install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status”
```

```
#2
install.packages(c('ddalpha', 'recipes'))
install.packages('caret', dependencies=True)
```

Errors:

```
Installing packages into ‘/home/nbuser/R’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message in install.packages(c("ddalpha", "recipes")):
“installation of package ‘ddalpha’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages(c("ddalpha", "recipes")):
“installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status”Installing package into ‘/home/nbuser/R’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘recipes’

Warning message in install.packages("caret"):
“installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("caret"):
“installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status”
```

I expect the caret library installed without any errors in Azure Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when path is not clear. So you need to set the lib yourself.

For example

```
.libPaths(C:/Program Files/R/)
```

Sometimes, if there is a space in the folder name, it may be not recognized it. Then, set other path or change folder name.

Comment: I logged into the shell of Microsoft Notebooks and saw the installed libraries are in `/home/nbuser/R` which is same when running in the notebook.

Also, I tried running the package installer from the terminal but getting the same error.

Comment: Is R program installed on C drive?

Comment: This is on Microsoft Azure notebook. The R is available under `/usr/bin/R` and all the libraries are in `/home/nbuser/R`. This is a Linux server provided by Azure Notebooks service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough knowledge about Linux servers. Ah, it will be helpful for you. :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619370/fatal-error-auc-cpp210-fatal-error-omp-h-no-such-file-or-directory